# Как добавить данные LocalStorage в postman?

Tags: веб-программирование, postman

Хочу отправить POST-запрос через PostMan, но мне нужно авторизоваться на том сайте, где хочу отправить запрос. Где добавлять куки - вижу, а вот где добавить данные LocalStorage - не вижу. Есть вообще тут такая возможность? Если да, покажите пожалуйста на скриншоте)

Comment: данные из локал стораджа передаются в самом запросе.... это может быть и гет параметр и параметр в body и как header...... как это будет конкретно отправлено - определяют разработчики....... локал сторадж - это просто хранилище данных на клиенте..... к отправке данных он не имеет ни малейшего отношения